# How to show different error messages in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form with different input types.Here I need to show error message depends on the user's input.

If fields are empty,I will show `Enter required fields`.
If email is invalid I need to show `Enter valid email`.

But My code displays only `Enter valid email` message even fields are empty.why its displaying like this?What wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#errorMsg').hide();
})
function submitForm() {
    $('#myForm').find('input,select').each(function () {
        var element = $(this).val() == undefined ? '' : $(this).val().trim();
        if (element == '') {
            $(this).addClass('borderDanger');
            $('#errorMsg').html('Enter all required fields');
            $('#errorMsg').show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('borderDanger');
            $('#errorMsg').html('');
            $('#errorMsg').hide();
        }
    })

    $('#myForm').find('input[type="email"]').each(function () {
        var emailRejex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
        if (String($(this)).match(emailRejex)) {
            $(this).removeClass('borderDanger');
            $('#errorMsg').html('');
            $('#errorMsg').hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('borderDanger');
            $('#errorMsg').html('Enter valid Email');
            $('#errorMsg').show();
        }
    })
}
```

```css
#errorMsg {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 9px;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top: 4%;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border: 1px solid #ebccd1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.borderDanger {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="errorMsg"></div>
<div id="myForm">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="email">
    <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Jquery validation plugin

Comment: Your regex validation is running 2nd. Regex validation fails on the empty string, that's why you see invalid email message. You need to check if the email address is empty or not first

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#errorMsg').html('Enter valid Email');
```

This part replace what ever is in '#errorMsg' , better way to show errors is liket this: (generate error variable with your error/errors then show at once)

```
var errors = [];
if(error){
errors.push("error 1");
}
if(error){
errors.push("error 2");
}
```

then show them at once:

```
 $('#errorMsg').html(errors);
 $('#errorMsg').show();
```

like this

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#errorMsg').hide();
})
function submitForm() {
  var errors = ''
    $('#myForm').find('input,select').each(function () {
      
        var element = $(this).val() == undefined ? '' : $(this).val().trim();
        if (element == '') {
            $(this).addClass('borderDanger');
            errors += 'Enter all required fields </br>'
            $('#errorMsg').html(errors);
            $('#errorMsg').show();
        }
        else {
          if($(this).attr('type') == 'email'){
             var emailRejex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
                if (String($(this)).match(emailRejex)) {
                    $(this).removeClass('borderDanger');
                    $('#errorMsg').html('');
                    $('#errorMsg').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('borderDanger');
                    errors += 'Enter valid Email'
                    $('#errorMsg').html(errors);
                    $('#errorMsg').show();
                }
          }
            $(this).removeClass('borderDanger');
        }
    })

    $('#myForm').find('input[type="email"]').each(function () {
       
    })
}
```

```css
#errorMsg {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 9px;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top: 4%;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border: 1px solid #ebccd1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.borderDanger {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="errorMsg"></div>
    <div id="myForm">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="email" />
      <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

[plankr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4a1BTbV0YJo4G3PqVAO4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you don't want invalid email message when textbox is empty

```
    $('#myForm').find('input[type="email"]').each(function () {
//Check if email is empty
     var element = $(this).val() == undefined ? '' :$(this).val().trim();
           if (element == '') return;
                        var emailRejex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
                        if (String($(this)).match(emailRejex)) { 
                         $(this).removeClass('borderDanger');
                         $('#errorMsg').html('');
                         $('#errorMsg').hide();
                        }
                        else{
                         $(this).addClass('borderDanger');
                 $('#errorMsg').html('Enter valid Email');
                 $('#errorMsg').show();
                        }
              })
```